# How can I override testcases in same report using extend report

Tags: selenium, automation, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

How can I override test cases for multiple executions in the same report?. Like if I run failed test cases multiple time then it should override the same file without losing other records.

In my case, it deletes all the old records from the file and adds the new one.

```
string path1 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Replace("\\bin\\Debug", "");
        string path = path1 + "Report\\index.html";
        ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(path);
        htmlReporter.Configuration().Theme = AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter.Configuration.Theme.Standard;
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Appending to Report
ExtentHtmlReporter and ExtentXReporter allow appending test information to an existing report.

Appending to HtmlReporter

```
htmlReporter.setAppendExisting(true);
```

Appending to ExtentXReporter
If you want to append to an existing report based on its ObjectId, use:

```
extentXReporter.setAppendExisting(true, reportId);
```

or:

```
extentxReporter.config().setReportObjectId(ObjectId id);
extentxReporter.config().setReportObjectId(String id);
```

If you want to append to an existing report based on reportName, use:

```
extentxReporter.setAppendExisting(true);
```

Note: If you have multiple reports with the same name, the append will be applied to the last-run report that matches the report-name.

Comment: Thank you, but these things are not working with the v 3.1.1